# Update the app's main scope object with dialog box inputs

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

In my application, I am trying to update the dialog box's text input value into the main controller.
`$scope.dialogText` in main controller is set to the dialog box's text input.

Say, I enter `pumpkin` in the dialog, and press ok, my app must show,

```
Dialog box's text comment is pumpkin
```

Instead it always shows,

```
Dialog box's text comment is
```

Jsfiddle is at, http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22555/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your controller needs to be changed as below: -

```
myApp.controller('tmplCtrl', function($scope, ngDialog){
  $scope.dialogText = ""
  $scope.loadSuiteDlg = function(){
  var prom = ngDialog.open({template : 'dialog', scope : $scope });
  prom.closePromise.then(function(res){
     $scope.dialogText = res.value;
   });
  };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/knu04nww/